# Editing really old posts

Tags: discussion, edits, old-questions

I got an edit on one of my most popular answers (85 upvotes), from almost 7 years ago, with the comment "Attitude removed from answer to be more helpful to others": https://stackoverflow.com/posts/374337/revisions.

Two things annoy me slightly with this edit. First, is it really necessary to edit a 7 year old accepted question with 85 upvotes with the motivation "to be more helpful to others". I mean, why did it get 85 upvotes if it wasn't helpful?

Second, making substantial edits to old questions often make things like comments incomprehensible when they refer to old revisions of the questions.

Are there any policies or guidelines covering these kinds of issues?

Comment: If you disagree with the edit, you can just roll it back. I would...

Comment: 1. What do you mean *"necessary"*? Literally, of course it isn't, but the edit *did* improve the answer (a meta-comment on asking questions is unlikely to help people looking for the rest of your answer), and just because it was already considered helpful doesn't mean it can't be made more so. 2. Then flag the comments as obsolete. Neither of these seems specific to *"really old posts"*.

Comment: Yes, I went in and edited your answer again, I hope that you don't mind. Someone made an edit to one of my answers. I thought the edit was suspicious, and wondered if it was part of a pattern of edits to other parts of the site. I think the editor has good intentions but is overzealous in matters of style, so I have made a small number of edits to clean up after this other editor. (By all means, revert the changes I made if you want.)

Answer (score 5):

> is it really necessary to edit a 7 year old accepted [answer] with 85 upvotes with the motivation "to be more helpful to others". I mean, why did it get 85 upvotes if it wasn't helpful?

**Absolutely.** In fact, if there is any identified style problem that a consensus would agree is a style problem, it becomes **more** necessary to address it, the more upvotes the answer (and especially the corresponding question) gets, and the more views the question gets.

The perfect may be the enemy of the good, but the good enough is the absolute nemesis of the better.

Stack Overflow is well established to be a "no fun allowed" zone, and we want the site to project a **professional, direct, non-discussion-forum** image. Like it says on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Ask questions, get answers, **no distractions**".

No matter how frustrating it may have been to deal with OP at the time, any written record of that is a **distraction for everyone else** who comes to read the question later. Therefore, it directly conflicts with the site's goals.

There's a comment section for a reason: to give feedback (which can be removed at any time as "no longer needed") explaining why the question needs improvement. If the obvious solution to a problem is "do a fresh checkout", and OP says "I don't want to do a fresh checkout" but doesn't elaborate, **then the question is unclear**, and should be downvoted and closed as such. If the question is missing necessary information about the contents of certain folders, **then it needs debugging details** and should be downvoted and closed as such.

My personal advice is to avoid the word "you" in answers completely. It risks coming across as accusatory. It also makes the answer sound more like a *conversation* with OP; but the OP and the author of the answer are two parties to this interaction, which has **literally countless others**. Aside from the risk of making them feel excluded, it just doesn't fit a professional Q&A format. Well written *documentation* gives imperative instructions and passive-voice suggestions, rather than saying "you should" or "you can". I have been editing answers on popular questions in the same spirit.

Answers **especially** should not use phrases like "as I'm sure you know". That projects a hostile tone and an assumption of bad faith (like "why are you asking about this?"). It doesn't help future readers understand, if they didn't already know; and it *doesn't provide a real benefit if they did know, either*. It's also just... that much more text to read.

> Second, making substantial edits to old questions often make things like comments incomprehensible when they refer to old revisions of the questions.

Right. Such comments are "No Longer Needed", and [should be flagged as such](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801). Moderators are very happy to remove these, the overwhelming majority of the time - they have served their purpose. In general, comments are **not intended** to persist for long periods of time (this should only happen if they meaningfully add to an answer in a way that, for some reason, can't or shouldn't just be edited into the answer). Persisting comments on everything all over the place is what happens on a discussion forum. **Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum.**

---

A little diversion here, to drive home the point that old, highly-upvoted content is **not necessarily any good**.

When I first joined Stack Overflow I answered a fair few questions. Then I basically took several years off, only dropping in for the occasional question of my own, and then "rediscovered" the site in 2020 (mainly for the reasons you'd expect). Nowadays when I go back and look at my old answers, I cringe a fair bit. There have been a couple that I totally rewrote (though covering the same material), including [one just yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523). That was my third most popular answer ever, BTW. And I very nearly deleted it and started from scratch, rather than just overwriting it.

I honestly actually regret [my most popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586) answer to some extent. If the closure reasons back then had been as refined (though IMO they still need work) then as today, and if I had the same understanding then as now of site policy and the site *purpose*, **I would not have attempted to answer**. I would have voted to close [the original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/02372a92-d7f9-4e04-9150-39d2a32d9df2/view-source) of the question as needing more focus. (It was also unclear and noisy, but that at least could be edited away; it also lacked a MRE for the problem reported as "it doesnt work with me" [sic].) The edit history for that question shows *heroic* efforts, and yet I'm still trying to get that question closed and find a better canonical duplicate for each aspect of the question. Over two million views, BTW.

Comment: I think you are being overzealous about removing the word "you". I peeked into your edit history and found cases where you have taken simple, clear phrases like "If X, you can Y." and replaced them with "If X, one option is Ying". IMO there's no question here; the first option is better. The first option uses a simpler grammatical structure, is phrased directly, and uses more common words; it is clearer. The notion that "well-written documentation uses [...] passive voice suggestions" seems to be unfounded; I was able to find **tons** of examples.

Comment: The "passive-voice suggestions" is actually an opinion.  I've seen formal documentation and report writing guidance from a number of professional organisations, including some reputable journals, research organisations, universities, and regulators.     There are some that *mandate* passive voice and others that mandate active voice.   Some organisations also advocate a conversational style (and assert such a style is easier to read).

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable in general to address the reader. However, documentation has the advantage that it's clearly "talking to" the person who searched for it, while the default assumption for a Q&A site is that it's "talking to" the person who asked. I do sometimes use "we", because in English that implies everyone (including future readers).

Comment: That section could probably be elaborated, but I think it would be better to start a new Meta question to have a discussion about ideal writing style and put together some kind of "style guide" (of course, I imagine will will allow considerable flexibility regardless).

Answer (score 2):

When you answer a question, your goal is to help out with the specific situation that a specific person encountered. However, later on, the people reading the question and answer will be other people who reach Stack Overflow from search tools.

Your answer may be exactly what that specific person needed--the person who asked the question--but afterwards, everyone else who reads the answer will be somebody else. It makes sense to edit answers so that they **focus on the question** and don't focus on the specifics of who is asking the question or how they asked the question.

### What Was Deleted?

Here are some deleted passages from the edit in question:

> (as I'm sure you know)

This is a comment about the person who asked the question, and it's not relevant to answering the question. It just gets in the way for future visitors.

> (That is the kind of information you have to provide in order to people to be able to troubleshoot the issue. Remember that we do not have access to your `setup`, so you have to explain it is such detail that we can figure out from your description what's wrong.)

This is an admonition for the person who wrote the question, it doesn't belong in the answer. To be honest, it probably doesn't belong in the comments either, but that's a separate discussion.

### How to Focus on the Question

Ask, "Is this useful to somebody else with the same question? Is this useful to somebody else who finds this page?" If both answers are "no", consider removing it.

### Old, Visible Posts Should Be Polished

The question, [What causes the SVN Error "Not a working copy"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374313/what-causes-the-svn-error-not-a-working-copy/374337), is currently sitting at 552k views. Maybe in another 10 years, it will hit 1M views. Who knows? It makes sense to improve the answer for future visitors.

As necessary, here is how you fix posts for future visitors:

1. Remove content that is irrelevant to future visitors.
2. Clarify parts that are confusing.
3. Incorporate relevant information from comments into the post.
4. Add links to documentation or other Stack Overflow posts to add context.
5. Fix spelling or grammar errors.
6. Fix non-material technical errors. (If the answer is *wrong,* don't try to fix it with edits. Instead, use downvotes or comments.)
7. Tag code blocks with the correct language, if they are not highlighted correctly. (This can be done without reformatting the code block. Note that the correct language can often be deduced from the question’s tags—there is no need to explicitly tag these code blocks.)

### Should You Edit Posts to Remove "You"?

No.

Rewording posts to remove the word "you" serves no purpose and can make the answer less clear. Only reword posts to achieve some specific goal, like clarity or correctness.

Here is an example of a bad edit in this vein, from the edit history of the same question:

Original text:

> If you get a `not a working copy` error, it means that Subversion cannot find a proper `.svn` directory in there. Check to see if there is an `.svn` directory in `contents`

Updated text:

> Check to ensure that there is an `.svn` directory in `content`. A `not a working copy` error means that Subversion cannot find a proper `.svn` directory in that folder.

The original text is better.

A paragraph that starts with "If you get an XYZ error..." is a nice paragraph to see, because if you **don't** get XYZ error, then you can skip the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: To the list: Fix the weird [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109) (often with 'lang-none'). Anything that is not pure code (command-lines, error messages formatted as code, content in other languages outside the main tag (e.g., CSS), some CSS content (pseudo elements), etc.) is weirdly syntax highlighted due to [the new syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) and ***how it was implemented by the company***.

Comment: [A sample](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52731543/4) of weird syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks, added. I never thought to use “none”… I always just used `<pre>` to disable syntax highlighting.